# How to add a permission to a file on ubuntu with wsl?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount, chmod

### What I want to do

I am using ubuntu on wsl.
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata
I want to change the permissions of the file, but it didn't work. (I don't know much about permissions and may be missing or incorrect in the question. I would be grateful if you could give me any information that I'm missing.)

---

### What I did

The execution result of `cat /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata` is as follows.

```
cat: /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata: Permission denied
```

I want to be able to read the file for the time being.

`$ chmod u-r /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata` The execution result is as follows.

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata': Operation not permitted
```

Also, the result of -l command is as follows.

```
---------- 1 root root 44366093 Jan 10 10:05 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Jan 10 10:25 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Oct 22 12:49 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Jan 10 10:25 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr
```

Do you know something?
I would be happy if you could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a simple case of using sudo.

The directory /usr and all the directories inside are owned by the root user and belong to the root group (see the string `root root` in the `ls -al` command)

try `sudo chmod u-r /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/chi_sim.traineddata`

Comment: I am really sorry to be too late for replying. As your advice, I did it by sudo command! I am really appreciate for your advice!

Comment: Brilliant, glad it worked for you, don't forget to accept an answer that answers your question ;-)

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten. Thank you for reminding me. Maybe, I have done.